# Terraform: Error building ARM Config - Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

As the terraform azurerm provider misses support for azure webapp access restrictions ([see github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3685)). We use a `null_resource` with `local-exec` to apply a access restriction:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<COMMAND
      az webapp config access-restriction add --subscription ${self.triggers.subscription_id} --resource-group ${self.triggers.resource_group} \
        --name ${self.triggers.web_app_name} --rule-name 'allow application gateway' --action Allow --vnet-name ${self.triggers.vnet_name} \
        --subnet ${self.triggers.subnet_name} --priority 100
    COMMAND
  }
```

Our terraform code is then later run by an azure DevOps Pipeline, which uses a Service Connection (with Service Principal) to authenticate with Azure. The following task is trying to apply the terraform resources:

```yaml
  - task: TerraformCLI@0
    displayName: "Terraform apply"
    inputs:
      command: 'apply'
      commandOptions: '--var-file="./environments/${{ parameters.environment }}.tfvars"'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.projectFolder }}'
      environmentServiceName: 'shared-${{ parameters.environment }}-001'
```

which results in the following Error:

```
Error: Error running command '      az webapp config access-restriction remove --subscription shared-staging-001 --resource-group rg-hub-network-staging \
        --name landing-webapp-hub --rule-name 'allow application gateway'
': exit status 1. Output: Subscription 'shared-staging-001' not recognized.
Command group 'webapp config access-restriction' is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

No we tried to replace the TerraformCLI@0 Task with either a plain bash script or a AzureCLI@2 Task.

We could not get az login to work in a plain bash script due to the missing Infos. The approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234110/how-can-a-script-access-service-connections-azure-devops-pipelines) does not work either.

Running the terraform commands inside a AzureCLI@2 Task looks promissing but causes some strange errors related to the service principal login:

```yaml
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Terraform init"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: shared-${{ parameters.environment }}-001
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        terraform init --backend-config="./environments/${{ parameters.environment }}_backend.tfvars"
```

This causes the following error:

```
Initializing modules...
- app-gateway in modules/app-gateway
- dummy1 in modules/BRZ365-AppService
- dummy2 in modules/BRZ365-AppService
- hub-network in modules/hub-network
- landing_zone_app in modules/BRZ365-AppService
- squad-area in modules/squad-area

Initializing the backend...

Error: Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).

To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'
auth method - instructions for which can be found here: 

Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.
```

Comment: Can you try to remove --subscription shared-staging-001 from local-exec? I'm not sure of this is really needed here.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I get the same error without the unkown subscription when removing the subscription:
Error: Error running command '      az webapp config access-restriction remove --resource-group rg-hub-network-staging \
        --name dummy2-webapp-hub --rule-name 'allow application gateway'
': exit status 1. Output: Command group 'webapp config access-restriction' is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
Please run 'az login' to setup account.

Comment: Can you try pass the subscription id and not the name

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally got this to work with the AzureCLI approach I described in the first post. I use `addSpnToEnvironment` (it adds the service provider credentials to the environment, as described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops)) and set the required parameters as described [by terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform).

```yaml
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Terraform"
        inputs:
          azureSubscription:  shared-${{ parameters.environment }}-001
          scriptType: bash
          addSpnToEnvironment: true
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
            export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
            export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId

            terraform init .....
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your script, substituting my subscription id, of course. I always get the error `Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.`

I even tried putting 'az login' in the inline script. Nothing works. Do you know what I could be doing wrong, or can you verify your solution still works?

Comment: @user658182 I think you need to put the "service connection name" in the "azureSubscription" field and not the actual SubscriptionID. That way works for me.

Comment: Excellent answer. In case you are using powershell core (by setting ```scriptType``` to ```pscore```), the syntax is like this: ```$env:ARM_CLIENT_ID = $env:servicePrincipalId``` and ```$env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET =  $env:servicePrincipalKey``` and ```$env:ARM_TENANT_ID =  $env:tenantId```

Answer (score 4):

I got through this with `local-exec`.

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<COMMAND
      az login --service-principal --username #{APP_ID}# --password #{SP_PASSWORD}# --tenant #{TENANT_ID}#
      az webapp config access-restriction add --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name} --name ${azurerm_app_service.example.name} --rule-name developers --action Allow --ip-address 130.220.0.0/27 --priority 200
    COMMAND

    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
```

Unfortunately I had to create another service principal for this purpose as I didn't want to reset the one used by Azure DevOps (but you can give it a try and reuse this one).

I used these commands:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name sp-for-cli

az role assignment create --assignee APP_ID --role Contributor
```

As next I declared variables APP_ID, SP_PASSWORD and TENANT_ID on my release pipeline with values given by command above.

As last step I added [token replace step](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens):

```
steps:
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in main.tf'
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform/drop'
    targetFiles: main.tf
```

Now when I run `az webapp config access-restriction show --resource-group example-resources --name example-app-service-for-cli` I get:

```
"ipSecurityRestrictions": [
    {
      "action": "Allow",
      "additional_properties": {},
      "description": null,
      "ip_address": "130.220.0.0/27",
      "name": "developers",
      "priority": 200,
      "subnet_mask": null,
      "subnet_traffic_tag": null,
      "tag": "Default",
      "vnet_subnet_resource_id": null,
      "vnet_traffic_tag": null
    },
```

The whole code you can find [here](https://github.com/kmadof/devops-terraform-manual).

Comment: I could not test your approach (as I got a different approach to work). But this looks fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when working with Terraform to setup resources on Azure.

When I run `terraform plan` I get the error:

```
│ Error: building AzureRM Client: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).
│ 
│ To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'
│ auth method - instructions for which can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret
│ 
│ Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 18, in provider "azurerm":
│   18: provider "azurerm" {
```

Here's how I solved it.

The problem was that I was authenticating Azure CLI with Terraform the wrong way. I was using the command below to authenticate it with a service principal:

```
az login --service-principal --username $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_APP_ID --password $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD --tenant $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID
```

The issue is that the command above does not authenticate you as a user, but as a service principal, which is not a supported way to authenticate using service principal by Terraform.

```
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "f8256ac9-e164-4ac6-a487-0f6e3dc17532",
    "id": "bec123cd-bead-43ba-90c6-5235cririe903",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "my-subscription-1",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "f8556ac9-e159-4ac6-a487-8r9erhwjw",
    "user": {
      "name": "r673reb62-bbf7-40e1-ab10-ry45640484",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
```

The right way to do this was to simply run the command below:

```
az login
```

Then the Azure CLI will open up a browser window where I will log in to my Azure account on the portal and get authenticated as a user. If you have multiple subscriptions, it will select your currently logged-in subscription as your default subscription.

```
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "f8256ac9-e164-4ac6-a487-0f6e3dc17532",
    "id": "bec123cd-bead-43ba-90c6-5235cririe903",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "my-subscription-1",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "f8556ac9-e159-4ac6-a487-8r9erhwjw",
    "user": {
      "name": "john.doe@my-domain.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "ghfjg6ac9-e164-7466-a487-0f6e3dc17hjr",
    "id": "rtkrt7f3d-51b2-7587-88b7-d29ftheruofw",
    "isDefault": false,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "my-subscription-2",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "f8556ac9-e159-4ac6-a487-8r9erhwjw",
    "user": {
      "name": "john.doe@my-domain.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]
```

**OR** if you desire to authenticate as service principal, then you will export the following variables using the provided variables names:

```
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="your-service-principal-appid"
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="your-service-principal-password"
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="your-current-subscription-id"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="your-tenant-id"
```

Now, you can run your `terraform plan` and everything will work fine.

**Resources**: [Configuring the Service Principal in Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform)

Comment: This is not a solution for the problem presented, as it is in a pipeline context and specifically for a service principal.  The last part, that you just copied from the Terraform site, does not just simply "work fine".

Answer (score 0):

Update November 2023

I made it work by using the ARM prefix, and changing my azurerm provider to 3.0

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @quadroid is perfect, which is so helpful and save my time a lot. set `addSpnToEnvironment` and use `export commands` to set Azure Environment Variables are keys to resolve the issue.

But it doesn't support [management group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview) (if you know AWS, it is similar as AWS cross account assume role) , only works with current subscription.

[Understand scopes for Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/scope-overview)

- management group
- subscription
- resource group
- resource

[image]

So the error I got is

```
Error: building account: unable to configure ResourceManagerAccount: subscription ID could not be determined and was not specified
```

I finally worked it out with management group and I can run terraform/terragrunt command to any subscriptions under this management group.

- use `addSpnToEnvironment` and set it to `true` (it adds the service provider credentials to the environment, as described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops))
- set Azure enironment variables as described [by terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform).

```
# these variables are automatically generated by `addSpnToEnvironment` set to `true`
export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId

# this variable need be input by pipeline's parameters or hardcode if you know its subscription id
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
or
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="$(subscription_id)"
```

The final pipeline for your reference

```yaml
parameters:
- name: subscription_id
  displayName: 'Azure Subscription ID'
  type: string

stages:
- stage: TerraformDeployment
  jobs:
  - job: TerraformDeployment
    displayName: TerraformDeployment
    steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Terraform"
        inputs:
          azureSubscription:  <replace_with_service_account_with_management_group_permission>
          scriptType: bash
          addSpnToEnvironment: true
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
            export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
            export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
            # it need be set via Environment variable, or get from parameters
            export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="$(subscription_id)"

            terraform init .....
```