# Terraform init does not run with the same login context as other terraform commands

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

When running an Azure Devops yaml pipeline I have a strange behaviour with:
terraform init when authenticating.

**Context**

This is the pipeline snapshot I try to run:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2                     
      displayName: 'Terraform init'                                 
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)                        
        scriptType: 'bash'                                               
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'                           
        inlineScript: |                        
          terraform init \
             -backend-config="resource_group_name=$(REMOTE_STATE_RG)" \
             -backend-config="storage_account_name=$(REMOTE_STATE_SA)" \
             -backend-config="container_name=$(REMOTE_STATE_CONTAINER)" \
             -backend-config="key=terraform.tfstate"
```

**My issue**

Instead initializing Terraform, I get this message:

> Initializing the backend... ╷ │ Error: Error building ARM Config:
> Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a
> Service Principal). │  │ To authenticate to Azure using a Service
> Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service
> Principal' │ auth method - instructions for which can be found here:
> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret
> │  │ Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a
> User Account. │  │

But if I try another terraform command **everything is fine**, for instance:

> ```
> - task: AzureCLI@2                                 
>   displayName: 'Terraform apply'                         
>   inputs:
>     azureSubscription: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)                        
>     scriptType: 'bash'                                               
>     scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'                                   
>     inlineScript: 'terraform apply --auto-approve terraform.tfplan'
> ```

**I am using last version of terraform.**

**My questions**

- Why is there a difference between init another terraform command ?
- What I should do for using an Azure Service Principal like other command ?

I read answers like:

[Terraform: Error building ARM Config - Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268776/terraform-error-building-arm-config-authenticating-using-the-azure-cli-is-onl)

But they suggest to pass SPN secret as a variable. I just have access to SERVICE CONNECTION and can't get this value.

I just don't understand why **init** is different

Thank you

**updates**

terraform: 1.5.5
azurerm: 3.68.0

my backend:

```
  backend "azurerm" {
  }
```

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using? What version of the AzureRM provider? What does your `backend` look like?

Comment: I updated the post with these informations

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet the problem isn't to do with init vs apply. You can't do an apply without running init first, so for your apply to have worked, you must have init'ed something. The problem is probably in the difference between the init in your pipeline and the init you did when you made the apply work.

The problem is probably to do with your remote state.  Init will need to access your remote state, so that's when init will have auth errors.

Answer (score 0):

In fact AzureCLI run:
az login –service-principal

This is not supported by azurerm. in fact this is exactely what is said by the error message.

So AzureCLI is not the right way to run terraform.

Better use dedicated task or script task.